# PHP DOM list element

Tags: php, object, dom, html-lists

I'm trying to add new element of html list (ul), result I get invalid html file

```
public function createChild()
{
    $args=func_get_args();
    $child = $this->dom->createElement($args[1]);
    $result=$args[0]->appendChild($child);
    return $result;
}
```

How I use it

```
$p=$tpl->createChild($div,'p');
$list=$tpl->createChild($div,'ul');
$tpl->createChild($list,'li');
```

Result

```
<div class="Menu" id="Base">
<p></p>
<ul><li></ul>
</div>
```

And if I trying add li in other places, don't get closing tag too.

Comment: Could it be because you are appending the `li` to the `div` instead of the `ul`?

Comment: In that case, it would have been added after the ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The li HTML tag normally needs a value.

You could try to use another addChild for li, with the value as a parameter.

```
if ($args[2] != '') {
   $child = $this -> dom -> createElement($args[1], $args[2]);
]
```

The second part of your

```
<li></li>
```

is omitted. For empty values use a space: '&bsp;'.
Maybe this is the result of some HTML errors on your page.

The result should be:

```
<div class="Menu" id="Base">
<p></p>
<ul><li>&bsp;</li></ul>
</div>


$tpl -> createChild($list, 'li', '&bsp;');
```

Make a HTML validation of the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a validator?

Depends on the doctype. This is *not invalid* HTML5 at least, it seems `li`s don't have to be closed

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

```
Tag omission in text/html:

An li element's end tag ***may be omitted*** if the li element is immediately followed by 
another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.
```

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
libxml_clear_errors(); because PHP Dom don't understand html5 tags